# Access Object3D Mesh Material in THREE.js r115

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I am used to alter Objects3Ds Materials in the THREE.js scene graph.

Now i switched to typescript and have some troubles accessing Mesh Materials (after creation)!
The docs and types state that there is no Object3D.material

I also dont see the .material anywhere on the Object3D during runtime!

To make it work with Typescript - can I just to cast it to Mesh?
Or how do I access the Mesh from Object3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material is on the Mesh object, which is inherits Object3D.

Check the docs of Mesh [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh)

Comment: so i basically have to check my scene for 'object.material' or 'instanceof Mesh' while traversing, right?